# How to bootstrap a loes function and estimate confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, regression, bootstrapping, loess

I keep on going around in circles trying to bootstrap confidence intervals for my data. I've only got very rudimentary knowledge about stats and am having trouble adapting the code such as [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

My aim is to be able to predict the mean, confidence intervals, and sd for n values (say, 300) along the x range of the data (ie. from 27.05575 to 144.75700, but can truncate the data if needed for the bootstrapping processes).

Sample code for generating the loess.

```
# create a data frame
df <- data.frame(
  DBH = c(27.05575, 30.10165, 41.36365, 48.31459, 64.64380, 64.88845, 65.55535, 75.12160, 79.40695, 113.27850, 114.68800, 120.68150, 125.24300, 130.27200, 132.17600, 144.75700),
  length = c(0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 1.5056656, 0.4686661, 1.5143648, 1.2282208, 0.3701741, 19.2412440, 51.3086010, 33.4588765, 254.6009090, 35.0538617, 59.5713370, 195.1270735),
  normalised = c(0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.005913827, 0.001840787, 0.005947995, 0.004824102, 0.001453939, 0.075574137, 0.201525600, 0.131416956, 1.000000000, 0.137681605, 0.233979278, 0.76640368)
)

model <- loess(normalised ~ DBH, data= df, span = .8)
xrange <- range(subData$DBH)
xseq <- seq(from=xrange[1], to=xrange[2], length=300)
pred <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(DBH = xseq), se=TRUE)
yfit = pred$fit

predictionDataFrame <- data.frame(xseq, yfit) %>%
  rename(DBH = xseq, normalised = yfit)

ggplot(data = predictionDataFrame, aes(x = DBH, y = normalised)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = DBH, y = normalised)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: loess with 0.8 smoothing]

Side note - I'd prefer a less smooth curve, but as there are some gaps in my data, I run into some weirdness when I use a lower smoothing parameter. Ie this is the curve for 0.6:

[image: loess with 0.6 smoothing]

Besides from the 'span' parameter, are there other ways to control the loes? Changing the other parameters doesn't seem to do much. However, using the `loess.boot` function from the `spatialEco` package, the fitted curves seem more targeted than just the raw `loess` function with 0.8 smoothing. This last image is a comparison of a couple of different measurements of mine using the `loess.boot` function from `spatialEco` (thick lines) and the `loess` function (dashed lines). I'd prefer not to rely on that package and go through the process manually so I understand what's happening.

[image: comparing loess predictions] predictions.

Comment: Write a function that fits the model you want on the data you give it, and returns the value at each of the 300 points you want. Then write another function that takes a bootstrap sample of data and calls your modeling function on it, passing the results on back. Then call that function on your data 1000 times, and take the mean and the SD of the results at each point.

Comment: Thanks George. Still a bit beyond my abilities - no chance you could write that out and I could integrate into my work? I have been trying to do that with other samples bootstrap code but can't get the hang of it. (no worries if not though!)

Comment: Can you do the first step, since that's the one that has choices in it (the loess parameters). Use the data you've got. Fit a loess model.

Comment: hi Gregor, updated the original post with your request

Comment: Great, can you do the next step? Put your loess-fitting code in a function that takes the data as input. I'd suggest taking either the maximum x range and the number of prediction points OR the x-values where you want a prediction as input too, as you want that to be the same every bootstrap sample, not dependent on the data.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor-thomas), you have to put your code for fitting the model and getting prediction in functions. It is then relatively straight forward to use e.g. `tidymodels` to apply bootstrap resampling to estimate uncertainty. (Though I give no guarantees that these estimates of uncertainty are statistically sound for whatever inference you will try to use them for.)

Here is an example where I've taken your code for fitting the model and making predictions as verbatim as possible from question and made them into functions, and then used a `tidymodels` approach to estimate the model and make predictions on 10k bootstrap samples:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(2023)

df <- data.frame(
  DBH = c(27.05575, 30.10165, 41.36365, 48.31459, 64.64380, 64.88845, 65.55535, 75.12160, 79.40695, 113.27850, 114.68800, 120.68150, 125.24300, 130.27200, 132.17600, 144.75700),
  length = c(0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 1.5056656, 0.4686661, 1.5143648, 1.2282208, 0.3701741, 19.2412440, 51.3086010, 33.4588765, 254.6009090, 35.0538617, 59.5713370, 195.1270735),
  normalised = c(0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.005913827, 0.001840787, 0.005947995, 0.004824102, 0.001453939, 0.075574137, 0.201525600, 0.131416956, 1.000000000, 0.137681605, 0.233979278, 0.76640368)
)

fit_loess_on_bootstrap <- function(split) {
  loess(normalised ~ DBH, data = analysis(split), span = .8)
}

extract_prediction <- function(model, xrange) {
  xseq <- seq(from = xrange[1], to = xrange[2], length = 300)
  pred <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(DBH = xseq), se = TRUE)
  tibble(term = xseq, estimate = pred$fit)
}

boots <-
  df %>%
  bootstraps(10000) %>%
  mutate(
    model = map(splits, fit_loess_on_bootstrap),
    preds = map(model, extract_prediction, xrange = range(df$DBH)),
    spline = map(model, augment)
  )

## Look at a sample of individual fitted loess curves:
boots %>%
  sample_n(100) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(spline)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(DBH, normalised)) +
  geom_line(aes(DBH, .fitted, group = id), alpha = .2) +
  geom_point(data = df) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
## Estimate CI using the percentile method:
results <-
  boots %>%
  int_pctl(preds)

results %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, .estimate, ymin = .lower, ymax = .upper)) +
  geom_ribbon(fill = "grey75") +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "DBH", y = "normalised") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**EDIT 23-04-03: Here is an example on how to extract the SD from each point.**

We can extract the predictions for each point from each bootstrap sample by unnesting our `preds` column. (The `preds` column is just a list of data frames, one for each bootstrap sample -- so to extract the predictions you could use any method of row binding them together, such as `boots_preds <- do.call("rbind", boots$preds)`).

If we then group by `term`, which denotes the point in the range, and use `summarize()`, we can summarize whatever you want at each point in the range --- including the standard deviation, mean, median, and so on. For instance:

```
## EDIT 23-04-03: Extract mean and sd from the boots:

results_sd <-
  boots %>%
  unnest(cols = c(preds)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(estimate)) %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  summarize(
    avg = mean(estimate),
    med = median(estimate),
    std_dev = sd(estimate)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

print(results_sd)

# A tibble: 300 × 4
    term      avg         med std_dev
   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  27.1 0.00131   0.000207   0.00252
 2  27.4 0.00116   0.000149   0.00231
 3  27.8 0.00101   0.000128   0.00211
 4  28.2 0.000872  0.0000926  0.00193
 5  28.6 0.000732  0.0000519  0.00176
 6  29.0 0.000595  0.0000146  0.00161
 7  29.4 0.000460 -0.00000783 0.00148
 8  29.8 0.000327 -0.0000393  0.00138
 9  30.2 0.000566 -0.0000133  0.00199
10  30.6 0.000423 -0.0000236  0.00187
# … with 290 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael. Just wondering how I can obtain the standard deviation at each point in the range? Cheers!

Comment: Added an example of how to do that :)